# Cross-platform way of constructing an FS path with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems, portability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qt equivalent of PathAppend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014145/qt-equivalent-of-pathappend)

Short story: does Qt 4 have an analog of Python's `os.path.join`?

Long story: I need to add a relative path to the application directory, `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` in the Right Way (TM), so that the code doesn't depend on the file system directory separator character.

Is merely joining QStrings and using "/" as the separator a good solution?

Comment: Why not using [QDir](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdir.html) or similar?

Comment: Because I do not see a QDir method that does exactly what I need. Could you please be more specific about what you suggest?

Comment: Operator overloading can be abused, but overloading `operator/` for paths is not. `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() / "MySubDir"` is perfectly reasonable code. Shame Qt4 doesn't have that.

Comment: the method QChar separator() will give you at least the separator you need to use

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either use "/" directly or use [`QDir::separator()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qdir.html#separator).  But in general use a [`QDir`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qdir.html) for this (which translates "/" to the platform specific path separator for you).

Answer (score 19):

From Qt 4.6 [`QDir`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qdir.html#details) documentation,

**Qt uses "/" as a universal directory separator in the same way that "/" is used as a path separator in URLs. If you always use "/" as a directory separator, Qt will translate your paths to conform to the underlying operating system.**

So, I guess `QDir` will be helpful for you.

Comment: +1 for docs. Anyways, `/` is a pretty universal seperator. It's default on POSIX, Mac OS, and supported (officially) by Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Just use "/" when staying in the Qt world.
To convert the path for non-Qt classes and functions etc., use QDir::toNativeSeparators( path ).